# Is there any way to calibrate the Gyroscope/Compass/Accelerometer in Windows Phone devices?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to use GART (http://gart.codeplex.com/) on a Windows Phone project and it requires the use of the Gyroscope.

Most of the times i feel the gyroscope isn't calibrated and it shows a wrong result.

Is there a way to calibrate the Gyroscope/Compass/Accelerometer in a Windows Phone?
Is there a way to know (programatically) if these sensors are not calibrated?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, use the `HeadingAccuracy`

for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202974(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: But that only tells me the accuracy, right?
No way to calibrate?